# Imported dependency injection configuration has no container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have issues accessing the `$container` object in one of Symfonys dependency injection configuration. I am just using the di-component, not the framework. There is a main configuration file which resides in the root directory of my project and imports some base configurations as well as some parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<imports>
    <import resource="consts.php"/>
    <import resource="src/Base/dependencies.xml"/>
</imports>

</container>
```

While the import of the second xml file works, the first file fails erroring with:

> Call to a member function setParameter( ) on a non-object in ...

The `consts.php` file is just a two-liner:

```
<?php
$container->setParameter('dir.root', __DIR__);
$container->setParameter('dir.data', __DIR__.'/data');
```

According to the [documentation on setting external Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html) everything should work, or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
In the script, which loads the DI-Container, I accidentally imported the `consts.php` manually. This led to the above error. Anyway, removing this import led to Symfonys `FileLoaderLoadException`, which is thrown, when there could no class be found, which can resolve the type of the file to be imported.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException' with message 'Cannot load resource "/Users/carsten/Workspace/PHP/black-tie/consts.php".' in /Users/carsten/Workspace/PHP/black-tie/vendor/symfony/config/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/Loader.php:73

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you initialized the continer with `$container = new ContainerBuilder();` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Does the DI not create the ContainerBuilder by itself, when importing a configuration into an existing one?

Comment: No, I was not referring to reinitialize the container inside the config file. I was asking how you initialize your container before importing the config file. Something like this?:
`$container = new ContainerBuilder();  $loader = new PhpFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));    $loader->load('services.php');` ?

Comment: Pretty much the same as XML: `$container = new ContainerBuilder(); $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(ROOT)); $loader->load($xmlContainer);`

Comment: You need to register a loader for each configuration type. The XmlFileLoader only knows how to load XMLs. You need the PhpFileLoader to load php files. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#setting-up-the-container-with-configuration-files.

Comment: Also, have a look at the DelegatingLoader to use multiple loaders.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved the issue :-)
Would like to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could guess that the reason is in the file paths. You trying to import file with

```
<import resource="consts.php"/>
```

so FileLoader looking for it in the root directory, but probably the file located in the app/config directory (or in another place). Check paths!